# Get array that contain a value provided in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have this array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => CMS_ADMIN
  [1] => CMS_ACADEMIC
  [2] => CMS_FINANCE
  [3] => HRM_HR
  [4] => SRM_D
  [5] => SRM_CNC
  [6] => SRM_TM
  [7] => SRM_DE
)
```

I would like to get the array by searching to the array value using the word provided. Let say I'm just provide the 'CMS' word, so how i'm gonna get the [0] => CMS_ADMIN, [1] =>CMS_ACADEMIC, [2] => CMS_FINANCE assign to the new array. Please help....

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Loop through the array, check each value if it starts with "CMS" and assign it to another array if so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a function that looks like this:

```
function array_filter_prefix($array, $prefix) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, $prefix) === 0) {
      $result[] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Given an input array, `$test`, you can then do this to get the result:

```
$result = array_filter_prefix($test, 'CMS');
print_r($result);
```

[Codepad here](http://codepad.org/GrGVpGET).

Answer (score 1):

batter style in PHP 5.3

```
$prefix = "CMS";

$new = array_filter($array, function ($str) use ($prefix) {
    return (strpos($str, $prefix) === 0);
});
```